# Can ‘it’ refer back to the meaning of a verb?

Tags: pronouns

For example,

I played with my dog. It [playing with my dog] was really interesting.

Can ‘it’ refer back to the meaning of ‘played’? I’ve only seen ‘it’ refers back to the meaning of a noun (in this case, only referring back to my dog).

Comment: Yes it can. I visited Japan last year. It was very interesting.

Comment: @Michael Harvey My dear teacher Michael, if A is B and A was mentioned, was B mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can, and it *does* refer to **the activity** both you and your dog were engaged in, to **the time** you spent together.

It can't refer to you because *it* isn't normally applicable to people.

It doesn't refer to your dog either because dog owners usually know the sex of their four-legged friends and refer to them by she/he. Also, *interesting* would be an unusual adjective choice towards a dog.